# Functional testing tools like Jameleon

Tags: c#, .net, functional-testing

Are there any functional testing tools like Jameleon (in java), available in the .net world?

**Purpose** I am testing an API written in C#.  I do not want to write unit or integration tests to test them (from QA perspective).  So, I just want to have a custom tool built up, through which I can decide to pass various test parameters and files.

Just for the sake of completion, Jameleon offers Jelly scripts which, like xmls are easy to configure.  These jelly scripts can then be executed like a test case.  Each tag of the jelly script is backed by a Java class which executes the functionality needed.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/specflownew/), it's a [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) for .Net

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I am actually looking for a tool that also has a GUI to deal with.

Comment: Specflow simply defines what to test, not how to test. You can easily couple it with http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/ or http://white.codeplex.com/